# How to check unique email in multiple table using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function unique_email($email)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('instructor, student');
    $this->db->where('instructor.email',$email); 
    $this->db->or_where('student.email',$email);
    $sql = $this->db->get();
    $result = $sql->num_rows();
    return $result;
}
```

In the above query I am simply trying to get unique email id in multiple tables but the above query doesn't work. I don't know why?

Comment: ?? Does ot work ??Not a very useful description. Does it fail? Does it get the wrong answer?

Comment: It would likely be better if you used a JOIN [Seach in here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#selecting-data) for how to use that properly

Comment: No @RiggsFolly it's not fail and it's work with 0 result.

Comment: I prefer JOIN if multiple tables keys are same.

Comment: Well I think `instructor.email` is equal to `student.email` in this case

Comment: It would probably be interesting to see the schema for these 2 tables

Answer (score 0):

Change your `TRUE` and `FALSE` as well check in controller:

**In Model**

```
 public function unique_email($email) 
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('instructor');
        $this->db->join('student', 'instructor.email = student.email');
        $this->db->where('instructor.email',$email);
    
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            # email exist
            return false;
    
        }
        else {
            # new/fresh email
           return true;
    
        } 
    }
```

**Controller :**

```
function email_exists($email) {
    $result = $this->Register_model->unique_email($email);

    if ($result == TRUE) {
        echo "Email Exists";
    } else {
        echo "New Email";
    }   

}
```

Comment: Not working @KUMAR. It shows `email exists` all times